# SharePoint online for mobile apps

Tags: sharepoint, azure-active-directory, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-api

I have a mobile app, in which am i need to read a list from SharePoint online. But I cannot able to login to the Sharepoint api using Azure AD.

I have tried many approaches like passing client ids, all the responses are like redirecting to the domain, but I don't have any domain since mines are mobile app.

So kindly help me to login to the Azure AD without redirectUrl

```
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/adminconsent
?client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e
&state=12345
&redirect_uri=https://localhost/myapp/permissions
```

In the above method after successfull login am redirecting to the mentioned redirect url but i dont have any domain, since i'm developing mobile apps.

I'm using ionic with angular app.

Kindly help is there any way to get a access token.

Comment: Is there any update? Is my answer helpful?

Comment: @AllenWu am working on it. Thanks for your response. Will update you once we are done.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need your own domain.

Redirect URI is unique to your application and it will return to this URI when authentication is complete.

For native app(mobile app), when authentication is successful, the code or token will be included in the redirect url.

You don't need to worry about it because if you are using MSAL or ADAL, you may select from the suggested Redirect URIs in Azure AD app Authentication page.

[image]